# I can't find my Web app when I SSH to my AWS Elastic Beanstalk instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've set up SSH to my AWS Elastic Beanstalk instance using

```
eb ssh --setup
```

and can successfully SSH to my environment. But I can't see my Web application. When I am connected I find myself in an empty directory (`ec2-user`) and when  I

```
cd /home
```

I just see

```
drwx------  3 ec2-user ec2-user 4096 Jan 15 21:37 ec2-user
dr-xr-xr-x 23 root     root     4096 Jan 15 21:03 ..
drwxr-xr-x  3 root     root     4096 Oct 22 23:29 .
```

Where is my Web application located?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Do `$ sudo find / -name <insert main file name here>` to find out.

For example:

```
$ sudo find / -name \*.php
/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT/info.php
/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT/index.php
/tmp/deployment/application/ROOT/info.php
/tmp/deployment/application/ROOT/index.php
```

Or, as you can see, in `/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT/`

You will notice, it depends on the platform. Python for example:

```
$ sudo find / -name application.py
/opt/python/bundle/2/app/application.py
```

Comment: Did I miss this in the docs? Or maybe I'm doing it wrong: how do I execute scripts I've uploaded (e.g. to perform database migration)?

Comment: [Follow up question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27985153/656912) about how to run once I've found.

Answer (score 19):

For anyone who doesn't want to wait for `find /`, I found my rails app at `/var/app/ondeck` before it successfully deployed and at `/var/app/current` after it succeeded.

Answer (score 2):

When you ssh into your instance, you are in the `~` directory. Type in `cd ..` to go to the parent directory, which is `home`. Then `cd ..` again to get to the root directory. There you can find the `var` folder, which will contain your files, as the others on here have pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

the content of your WAR is in `/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT` resp. `/usr/share/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT`