# Can I have all new files added to a directory automatically added to Git?

Tags: git

Is there a way to configure Git to automatically add any new files that are added to a directory?

I know how to do this from the command line; but is there a way to have it happen automatically?

Comment: I don't believe it's possible to add new files and commit in a single command. you could create a bash alias that does something like `git add .; git commit -a'

Comment: So no config to do it either, right (e.g., a `.alwaysadd` file)?

Comment: One could suggest to create a daemon based on libfam/inotify, but this seems to be an overkill.

Comment: And yes, there's no such a config option or something like that

Comment: Some IDEs will do this.  I believe the InelliJ family of IDEs does. Fwiw.

Comment: @Oakley: I'm using PyCharm; any idea how I set it up there?

Comment: @raxa... Do you have git set up in the IDE?  If so, when you create a new file, it should ask you if you want to add to git, with a checkbox to make that the default behavior.

Comment: @Oakley: I commit from within the IDE, but the are added by code, not within the IDE.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius the files are probably in the IDE's ignore list. Go to settings -> version control -> ignored files.

Comment: @NickHumrich: They're not ignored.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius Might be due to the first item on: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/confirmation.html but at this point you might want to ask a different question about intellij and auto-adding files for the intellij community.

Comment: @NickHumrich: Not sure I follow. The files are being added outside the IDE (by code running). I think any of the IDE features mentioned there refer to files "newly created" *in the IDE*, right? It's going to be up to Git to add ones created outside the IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know where the new files are located (at least enough to use path syntax and wildcards to describe the location) then you can accomplish this with a pre-commit [Git hook](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks).

For example, if you have [Flask-Migrate](https://flask-migrate.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) database migrations in your project's `.db_migrations` folder you can ensure that they are all added before your commits by placing

```
git add .db_migrations/versions/*.py
```

in your project's `/.git/hooks/pre-commit` file.

Comment: Note that this will not work for commits from within some IDEs (like [PyCharm](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-14909)), presumably because some hooking they do themselves.

Comment: Tools like Tower [will respect](http://www.git-tower.com/help/mac/faq-and-tips/faq#faq-11) the hook, even though they will not show the addition among proposed changes (since previewing changes presumably relies on `--dry-run`).