# Where does elastic beanstalk t2 server store my node.js app files?

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

From an architecture perspective I'm trying to get a better understand of how and where files deployed to eb (t2) server are stored.

I see some .zip files in s3 that show when I upload something via the eb interface, though how/where exactly does this get end up on my ec2(t2) server?

Answer (score 180, accepted):

It's in the `/tmp/deployment/application` folder during deployment and the  moved to `/var/app/current` afterward.

In case you search them, the node logs are in `/var/log/nodejs/nodejs.log` and the application will bind to `8081` no matter what PORT environment variable you set in the Environment Variables in the console.

Comment: I am using eb deploy every time to upload my changes to server file code. Can I directly make changes to /var/app/current directory.

Comment: That's against the best practices @vgokul129. If you have to log on to server to make changes then you are not really using eb for streamlined deployment. Also, eb can create multiple instances with load balancer, so changing something in one instance will not change it on all instances.

Comment: This directory location should really be in the AWS documentation, as far as I'm aware I haven't found it anywhere.

Comment: @XanT - I just found it here under "volumes" https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_v2config.html#create_deploy_docker_v2config_dockerrun

Comment: note this is under `/var/log/web.stdout.log` for linux2

Answer (score 15):

The top answer seems to be still working in November of 2020 for node app (nuxt app in my case)

```
/var/app/current
```

Comment: true as of Feb 17 2021 for NodeJS

Comment: Still true as of May 2022

Comment: Still true as of October 2023

Answer (score 8):

As a more general answer (not node.js-specific), check `eb-engine.log` from your Elastic Beanstalk environment.

*Where are the logs?* In Elastic Beanstalk's online interface in the sidebar of your environment.

```
...
2021/06/12 22:40:34.097454 [INFO] app source bundle is zip file ...
2021/06/12 22:40:34.097460 [INFO] extracting /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/app_source_bundle to /var/app/staging/
2021/06/12 22:40:34.097470 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c /usr/bin/unzip -q -o /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/app_source_bundle -d /var/app/staging/
2021/06/12 22:40:34.138333 [INFO] finished extracting /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/app_source_bundle to /var/app/staging/ successfully
...
```

Interpretation:

1. `app_source_bundle` was uploaded to `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/` initially
2. `app_source_bundle` was extracted to `/var/app/staging/`

If Elastic Beanstalk deployment is successful, you can find the running app's code in `/var/app/current` (as Manuel pointed out).

Answer (score 3):

`/var/app/current` may be outdated. It doesn't exist on my instance.
As said there [I can't find my Web app when I SSH to my AWS Elastic Beanstalk instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27973619/i-cant-find-my-web-app-when-i-ssh-to-my-aws-elastic-beanstalk-instance), for python the app is in `/opt/python/bundle/2/app/`
Otherwise use `find` to search for the location (look at the link).

Comment: Interesting, wonder if its in a different place for python apps? As I was originally looking for node.js files.

Comment: You may be using Amazon Linux, in which this path appears to be correct. If you are using Amazon Linux 2, the accepted answer is the correct one.

Comment: For me it was `opt/python/bundle/*22*/app/`