# Where is my socket server on AWS EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, socket.io

I have taken over a project that has an AWS ec2 elasticbeanstalk instance running a socket.io server.

I have logged in via and done the following steps.

1. `SSH` in
2. `cd /var` directory.
3. `ls > account  app  cache  db  elasticbeanstalk  empty  games  kerberos  lib  local  lock  log  mail  nis  opt  preserve  run  spool  tmp  www  yp`
4. I can't see to find the socket server code? Nor the logs for the socket server?

I am not sure where they would be located.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where does elastic beanstalk t2 server store my node.js app files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28245224/where-does-elastic-beanstalk-t2-server-store-my-node-js-app-files)

Comment: Followed this link and there is no /application folder.

Answer (score 0):

There are myriad methods to get code on to a server and to run it. Without any information about the code or the OS or anything else, assuming its a Linux based OS, if I’m looking for something and know *what* it is, I can usually find it by searching for a string that I know I will find inside at least one of the files on the server.

In this case, since its a socket.io, I’d search for socket.io:

```
grep -rnw '/' -e 'socket.io'
```

The result will show me all files, including the full path, that contain “socket.io”, and you should be able to determine where the code is pretty quickly.

Comment: That shows me where the socket.io is, but not my server.js file.  I found one in the current directory, but if I edit the server.js file in the current directory and then reboot the server the server.js file in the current directory is back to the orig.