# How to install poppler and setup pdf2image on elastic beanstalk

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, poppler, pdf2image

I want to convert PDF to jpeg on my elastic beanstalk python application.

I found that pdf2image and poppler can perform the conversion. I run the python application on local successfully.

However, for using pdf2image and poppler, I need to install poppler and change the path in pdf2image.py. Is it possible to perform these operation on elastic beanstalk?

I installed poppler by "$ yum install poppler-utils"

Installed:
poppler-utils.x86_64 0:0.26.5-43.amzn2

I need the path of the poppler. How can I find it?

Comment: Well, did you try to do anything towards that?

Comment: I found the pdf2image.py on ec2 but I can't find the poppler/bin which is the path I need

Comment: Sadly your question is not clear and lacks details. Did you even install poppler? You have to describe in full details of what exactly are you doing.

Comment: I have installed poppler by $ yum install poppler-utils. I am looking for the path of the poppler on EC2. On my local windows PC, the path I need is like "C:\Program Files\poppler-0.68.0\bin". I want to find the similar things on EC2 to config the pdf2image.py.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27973619/i-cant-find-my-web-app-when-i-ssh-to-my-aws-elastic-beanstalk-instance).

Using`$ sudo find / -name <insert main file name here>` to find poppler

Answer (score 0):

All the poppler tools, such as `pdfimages` will be in

```
/usr/bin
```